# How to query keyboard modifiers in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, modifier-key

Qt offers this with  [QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers). What is the QML way?

Answer (score 4):

In QML there exists the `KeyEvent` (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keyevent.html) for further details) that has a [property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keyevent.html#modifiers-prop) named `modifers`.
It contains a bitwise combination of the available modifiers.

It follows an example taken directly from the documentation above mentioned:

```
Item {
    focus: true
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if ((event.key == Qt.Key_Enter) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier))
            doSomething();
    }
}
```

For the complete list of the available modifiers, please refer to the official documentation.

Comment: Thats fine but I want to query the cached modifiers outsiden an event handler.

Comment: Oh, oK, got it. Well, what do you have in place of `QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers`? The same static method. Export it from the C++ layer to the QML one and that's all. Why can't you do that?